# Как добавить переменную с математическим действием

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт который показывает дистанцую между двумя пунктами. (Google Map).
Как сделать чтобы скрипт эту дистанцию делил на 3 и умнажал на 2 к примеру, и выводил как цену в html.

> ```
>  dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
> ```

https://codepen.io/richeydesign/pen/GoOaYP - вот сам скрипт

```
 var source, destination;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
  new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtSource'));
  new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtDestination'));
});

function GetRoute() {
  var ele = document.getElementById("loader");

  ele.style.display = "block";

  //*********DISTANCE AND DURATION**********************//
  source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
  destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: [source],
    destinations: [destination],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
      var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
      var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
      dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
      dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";

    } else {
      alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
    }
    ele.style.display = "none";

  });
}
```

Comment: Логично, что: `"Distance: " + (parseFloat(distance) / 3 * 2) + "<br />";`